# Grails 3.3 @Service annotation not making bean for abstract service?

Tags: java, spring, grails

For example, I have a service like this:

```
@Service(MyDomain)
abstract class MyDomainService {
    abstract List<MyDomain> list(Map args)
    ....
}
```

I find that if I create a service like this(in abstract way), grails will not make a bean named `myDomainService`, so that I cannot call this service in another service.

```
class MyOtherService {
    MyDomainService myDomainService

    def method() {
        myDomainService.list() // NPE. Also Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.beanDefinitionNames could not find any bean with name myDomainService.
    }
}
```

And also, `@Autowired` is not working for me.

But I don't know why controller could use this service properly:

```
class MyController {
    MyDomainService myDomainService  // it works
}
```

I want use this service in another service. What should I do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In GORM data services you can use Interfaces an abstract classes, here I quote the documentation

> If you come across a method that GORM doesn’t know how to implement,
>   then you can provide an implementation by using an abstract class.

In you example you provide a list method that can be implemented by GORM, so you can use an interface, for example and having a Person domain class as an example try

```
package app.demo

import grails.gorm.services.Service

@Service(Person)
interface IPersonService {
    List<Person> list()
}
```

If you need to implement a method that GORM doesn’t know how to, then you can try in for example `PersonService.groovy`

```
package app.demo

import grails.gorm.services.Service

interface IPersonService {
    List<Person> list()
}

@Service(Person)
abstract class PersonService implements IPersonService {

    List<Person> find(final String name) {
        Person.where { name == name }.list()
    }
}
```

In this way there should be no problems in injecting services into others or into controllers, for example here I am injecting PersonService in EmailService at EmailService.groovy

```
package app.demo

class EmailService {

    PersonService personService

    void send() {
        List<Person> personList = personService.find('ana')

        personList.each { Person person ->
            println "Sending email to $person.name $person.email"
        }
    }
}
```

And in a controller injecting EmailService

```
package app.demo

class PersonController {

    EmailService emailService

    def index() {
        emailService.send()

        render 'sending'
    }
}
```

I added the injection example of the service in another service and in the controller, maybe there is something that is relevant to you. I also attach the demonstration repository I [hope](https://github.com/ilmoralito/app.demo) you find it useful

Comment: Thanks. But it's still not working. I try to follow your demo, but still no bean, and also I can't inject my service into another service.

Comment: I know. I read the doc again. So data service is not a bean. If I use a abstract class as data service, then I can't use `@Autowired` to find the service. I have to inject `HibernateDatastore` and use `BookService bookService = hibernateDatastore.getService(BookService)` to get the service.

Comment: I find that data service cannot use `@Autowired` to inject into another service sine it's an AST transformation. But the official document said that `You can then obtain the service via Spring autowiring: @Autowired BookService bookService`. I try to do this but I get an error:   `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'paylogService'`

Comment: I added more information to the answer, by the way here I am using grails 3.3.8

Comment: How about inject the service to another abstract class service?

Comment: I'm using Grails 3.3.6, but I've already tried to upgrade to grails 3.3.8, still not working. When I inject a service to another without `@Autowired`, will get a NullObject, with `@Autowired`, will throw `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException`.

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question - injecting services wasn't the issue. Bean registration failing and lack of autowiring were the issues.